# How to add css class on my for loop for textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have issue regarding my validation for textbox string null, i did do a for loop to count textbox which are null, but my problem is how am i going to add a css style with red background on null textboxes if i am using a for loop. i already have the css style example: (txtNumberOfDaysCovered.cssClass= "form-control border-danger")

my for loop:

```
 string[] countTextbox = new string[8];
 countTextbox[0] = txtEndDate.Text;
 countTextbox[1] = txtLessLeaveTaken.Text;
 countTextbox[2] = txtnumberOfDaysCovered.Text;
 countTextbox[3] = txtoperation.Text;
 countTextbox[4] = txtposition.Text;
 countTextbox[5] = txtStartDate.Text;
 countTextbox[6] = txtThissApp.Text;
 countTextbox[7] = txApprover.Text;

 for (int i = 0; i < countTextbox.Length; i++)
 {
     if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(countTextbox[i]))
     {

         ValidationMessage.Text = "Please fill up all the required fields";
         ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", "<script>$('#modal_form_inline').modal('show');$('#modal_form_inline_Confimation').modal('hide');</script>", false);
                return;
     }

}
```

i just can't simple do these ff code: `countTextbox[i].cssClass = "form-control border-danger"`

Comment: You know form validation already exists right?

Answer (score 0):

> i just can't simple do these ff code: countTextbox[i].cssClass =
>   "form-control border-danger"

```
string[] countTextbox = new string[8];
```

`countTextbox` is String Array. You can not assign cssClass to it.
All you need is a Texbox there.

Answer (score 0):

```
  TextBox[] countTextbox  = new TextBox[8];
        countTextbox[0] = txtEndDate;
        countTextbox[1] = txtLessLeaveTaken;
        countTextbox[2] = txtnumberOfDaysCovered;
        countTextbox[3] = txtoperation;
        countTextbox[4] = txtposition;
        countTextbox[5] = txtStartDate;
        countTextbox[6] = txtThissApp;
        countTextbox[7] = txApprover;

        for (int i = 0; i < countTextbox.Length; i++)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(countTextbox[i].Text))
            {

                countTextbox[i].CssClass = "form-control border-danger";
                ValidationMessage.Text = "Please fill up all the required fields";
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", "<script>$('#modal_form_inline').modal('show');$('#modal_form_inline_Confimation').modal('hide');</script>", false);
                return;
            }


        }
```

Solved it!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Form Validations` for this but anyways you wants to do in that way you can do something like below not tested(Not Compiled) as well but you'll have an idea

```
var ListOfTextBoxes = new string[] { "txtEndDate","txtLessLeaveTaken","txtnumberOfDaysCovered","txtoperation","txtposition","txtStartDate","txtThissApp","txApprover"};
ListOfTextBoxes.ForEach(m => 
{
    var textbox = (TextBox)FindControl(m);
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox.text))
    {
       textbox.cssClass = "form-control border-danger";
    }
 });
```

Check [Control.FindControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info.

Comment: Thanks guys. i'll add the following code as comments for me to get better I really appreciate it  :)